# reducing video sizes from large gigabytes to smaller kilobytes

Tags: java, avi

I will like to know if there is a possiblilty of converting the size of video files from gigabyte to small kilobyte sizes and for the files to still be of high quality resolution and can be played on a flat screen.

Comment: I guess it depends on how long the video is. <1 Second maybe?

Comment: With Java? You should know that there always is a tradeoff between file size and quality so your question is not well specified...

Comment: If this was easily done why would anyone save the video files in gigabyte size from the beginning? To reduce the file size you need to either lower the resolution or the quality, or both.

Comment: Depends on the flat screen resolution... *If* it was possible, there'd be no need for Bluray ;)

Comment: Open the GB video in a hex editor , delete random chunks till you achieve the desired size . I doubt that it'll be playable on a flat screen , but hey , at-least we're saving space .

Answer (score 1):

Compressing a video from N Gigabytes to N Kilobytes is a one million-fold reduction in size. That's one pixel-worth of output for each 1 million input pixels. That level of compression / reduction is inevitably going to give you a drastic reduction in resolution and frame rate ... at best.

Actually, I'd be surprised if you could get more than a 100-fold reduction before the loss in picture quality became severe.